# Build errors with webrtc when using openssl instead of boringssl

Tags: openssl, webrtc

I am trying to build stable branch 57 of webrtc using openssl instead of boringssl. Here are my commands:

```
gn gen out/Default --args="is_component_build=false rtc_build_ssl=false rtc_ssl_root=""C:\DevThirdParty\openssl-1.0.2k"""
ninja -C out/Default
```

However, the build fails midway with the following errors:

```
[12/1633] CXX obj/webrtc/base/rtc_base/opensslstreamadapter.obj
FAILED: obj/webrtc/base/rtc_base/opensslstreamadapter.obj
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64/cl.exe" /nologo /showIncludes /FC @obj/webrtc/base/rtc_base/opensslstreamadapter.obj.rsp /c ../../webrtc/base/opensslstreamadapter.cc /Foobj/webrtc/base/rtc_base/opensslstreamadapter.obj /Fd"obj/webrtc/base/rtc_base_cc.pdb"
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(139): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(139): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(139): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(143): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(143): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(143): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(254): error C3646: 'rbuf': unknown override specifier
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(254): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(255): error C3646: 'rrec': unknown override specifier
c:\devthirdparty\openssl-1.0.2k\openssl\dtls1.h(255): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[21/1633] CXX obj/webrtc/modules/modules_tests/screen_capturer_integration_test.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Here is the code snippet from dtls1.h:

```
struct dtls1_retransmit_state {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *enc_write_ctx; /* cryptographic state */
    EVP_MD_CTX *write_hash;     /* used for mac generation */
#  ifndef OPENSSL_NO_COMP
    COMP_CTX *compress;         /* compression */   <=== LINE 139
#  else
    char *compress;
#  endif
    SSL_SESSION *session;                            <== LINE 143
    unsigned short epoch;
};
```

Is there another step I am missing? Regards.

Comment: *`Note: C++ does not support default-int`* - OpenSSL must be compiled with a C compiler, not a C++ compiler. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. Later, you can compile programs and apps with a C++ compiler. But the library has to be built with a C compiler.

Comment: Did you configure OpenSSL with `no-comp`? `ifndef OPENSSL_NO_COMP` comes from `<openssl/opensslconf.h>`. Maybe you can try to include it in `dtls1.h`? That is, add `#include "opensslconf.h"` to  `dtls1.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is in WebRtc's opensslstreamadapter.cc file. The includes are listed as:

```
#include <openssl/dtls1.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

After reversing the order, the compilation goes through.